# seam-gen and flex

Tags: seam

I have integrated  seam and flex with FlamingoDS
I got html file from mxml file and I stored it in WebContent folder it's fine
then I want to create link named as 'Plan' in menu.xhtml 
My aim is to get that html file when i clicked on this button I don't know what to do for that 
so, I have created some test.xhtml in that top element is the 
for the template attribute this element I have given the template.html
and I used 
then for 'Plan' link I gave the view="/test.xhtml" 
It's fine when I clicked on that link I am getting the test.seam file which includes our html file but this html file is coming in some fixed area with scroll bars only eventhough there is a lot of space to fit 
Please  help...... me

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it is very difficult to read your post. Please format it more readable.

Secondly, we can only guess what's wrong when we cannot see any code. But my hunch is that you are using s:decorate that includes some formating you are not aware of. This comes in standard seam-gen. Try removing that s:decorate stuff or point to another style you wish to use.